How to query certificate transparency logs to get certificates from certain periods/dates?
I'm trying to access Certificate Transparency (CT) logs from a specific date and analyze all the CTs that were appended during that time.
Is there a way to access the known CT logs via an API or any other means? I'm interested in retrieving the CT data.
I have tried going through crt.sh to see if there was a way to find old certificates and analyze them but I couldn't find anything.

You can read RFC6962 for the CT logs APIs. This doc tells you how to fetch the entries from the CT logs.
https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency-community-site/blob/master/docs/google/fetch-logs.md
For crt.sh, there is a read replica database (schema). If you have the PostgreSQL client software installed, you can login as follows:
$ psql -h crt.sh -p 5432 -U guest certwatch

